# MRTK RC1 Touch event from every angle of a cube

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, sample, mrtk

I tried to make touch event from every angle of a cube, but I can't make NearInteractionTouchable to cover whole cube. It is just cover half of my cube box collider.

https://gph.is/g/aXMVxOZ

I tried the touch sample from example scene, and it triggered touch event from any angle of the collider.

https://gph.is/g/EJ0xlNZ

Scene configuration and unitypackage:

1. Unity Version 2018.3.11f1
2. MRTK RC1
3. Import MRTK, create scene, add cube, add near interaction touchable
4. Create simple script with based IMixedRealityTouchHandler to print something on Touch Started

[image]

unitypackage:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjASC8dheotupcQxY45ydz0qUn0eeA

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the .gifs could you please update your question post a configuration of the box gameobject, or a .unitypackage with your setup that I can import? I would like to be able to reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: @JuliaSchwarz hi, sorry for my late reply. I have update my post with cube screenshot and also unitypackage. It seems that it is still error on my end

Comment: hi @JuliaSchwarz, any update on this one ? thanks

Comment: I would recommend trying to use the NearInteractionTouch script to check if that script receives events, since you may not be listening to the events properly. In your setup I can see that you don't actually have a script that is listening for touch events present on the game object. It would be good to add whatever code you use to listen for touches on that Cube gameObject, and then also to share how you are listening for touch events.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my very late respond on this, I was on something else. I did use NearInteractionTouch to receives the event, but I had another script that capture it by implement IMixedRealityTouchHandler on my script named TouchSample.cs (like my attach pic). Maybe I did not listening to the events properly on my scripts. I will looking and trying to learn from HandInteractionTouch to implement the class. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it looks like to answer #1, I *am* able to make a cube that is touchable from 6 sides, using the following configuration. I am able to touch the cube from all six sides.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I had same value of all numbers on near interaction touch.

Answer (score 0):

**This is current status of the kit, might be change in the future.**

Thanks for Julia at HoloDeveloper Slack on giving current status / detail of **Near Interaction Touchable** script.

Here they are:

1) how can I make my cube touch-able from all sides

2) how can I get the near interaction touchable to cover the entire face of a cube

**Answer:**

for 1) currently **nearinteractiontouchable**  will just dispatch to a surface, so to make a cube touchable from 6 sides you would need to add 6 nearinteractiontouchables, one for each side of the cube.

for 2) it sounds like your configuration is wrong.

From me on number 2, it was my wrong config, I was trying different number of Local Center, Up, Forward and Bounds number.

For those who has another thought or case that similar to this one, please make comment or add your own solution.

Thank You

Comment: Just wanted to let you know there is a pull request out in MRTK to add ability to touch a volume instead of just a surface: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/pull/4263#pullrequestreview-240994492

Comment: @JuliaSchwarz Thank you so much for information and working out this feature in MRTK. This is really awesome ! I'll try that working feature branch.